# How to draw a Horizontal line between two LinearLayouts in Android

Tags: android, android-layout

[image]

This is my Current screen :

```
   <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/title"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/radial_gradient">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/layout1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <com.cognistrength.caregiver.cogniutils.CSTextView
                    android:id="@+id/button"
                    android:layout_width="45dp"
                    android:layout_height="45dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="right"
                    android:layout_marginRight="34dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="28dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/purple_circular_layout"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="1"
                    android:textColor="@color/milk_white"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="@color/milk_white"
                    android:text="Profile"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"/>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/layout2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/layout1"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <com.cognistrength.caregiver.cogniutils.CSTextView
                    android:id="@+id/button2"
                    android:layout_width="45dp"
                    android:layout_height="45dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="right"
                    android:layout_marginRight="34dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="28dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/purple_circular_layout"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="2"
                    android:textColor="@color/milk_white"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="@color/milk_white"
                    android:text="Familly"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"/>
            </LinearLayout>


            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/layout3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/layout2"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <com.cognistrength.caregiver.cogniutils.CSTextView
                    android:id="@+id/button3"
                    android:layout_width="60dp"
                    android:layout_height="45dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="right"
                    android:layout_marginRight="34dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="28dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/purple_circular_layout"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="3"
                    android:textColor="@color/milk_white"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="@color/milk_white"
                    android:text="Health Record"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"/>
            </LinearLayout>

        </RelativeLayout>
```

Using this XML I am able to plot 3 circular text-view inside relative layout. I want to plot horizontal line between one and two and two and three text-view as given Screen below please suggest me how to achieve this. I am trying to apply view but not able to set eject below the screen.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement view between both the layout

```
<View
    android:id="@+id/view_firstName"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="2dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:background="@color/hintcolor"

    />
```

Comment: can anyone let me know the reason of down grading the question ..please clarify

Answer (score 0):

Just add a `FrameLayout` or `ImageView` between them and draw whatever you want on them.

Comment: can u please suggest me with some Controls coz i have tired not able to do

Answer (score 0):

you can use a view like below code between two layout with 1 dp height

```
<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:background="#000"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add following the View between your layouts.

```
<View
    android:width="match_parent" 
    android:height="1dp"
    background="yourColor"/>
```